# How to detect and separate Corrupt/Unreadable PDFs and password protected PDFs from a directory using python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a directory containing about ~ 1,00,000 multipage PDFs.
I want to separate Corrupt/Unreadable and Password protected PDFs from this directory using python.
Need a good and fast solution as I might need to do it for large number of files in future.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [PyPDF2](https://realpython.com/pdf-python/). Loop over all files in the directory using `os.listdir()` and try opening each one, and store the name of each one that gives you an error. You can also place them in two different directories depending on whether opening a file gives you an error using simple `try/except`.